# How to add Custom Thumbnail in Home Page in blogger?

Tags: html, blogger

I want to add a custom thumbnail to my home page. Like when i share my website to social networking sites, I want my custom thumbnail to be previewed. What should I do to achieve this? Please help me.

My site is http://www.technocombo.com on which if i share it to social networking sites, shows my favicon as thumbnail. PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use [Open Graph](http://ogp.me) to do it.

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="...">
<meta property="og:url" content="...">
<meta property="og:title" content="...">
<meta property="og:description"...">
<meta name="description" content="...">
<meta property="og:image" content="...">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpg">
<meta property="og:image:alt" content="...">
```

and then look at the result

https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/